# Chrome: How to view bookmarks, saved to Reading List folder

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Chrome allows me to save bookmarks to a "Reading List" folder which, in my case, was selected by default. However, when I look in my bookmarks manager, there is no such folder.

How do I view the bookmarks saved to this "Reading List" folder?

[image: Bookmark to Reading List]

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl+Shift+B and see if there is a 'Reading List' folder underneath the address bar now...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ +1. That's the only other place it could be.

Comment: Thanks. There's no Reading List folder underneath the address bar

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the icon directly to the right of the URL field.  It looks like a star with three dashes on the right.  When you hover over it, the tooltip reads "Hub (Favorites, reading list, books, history and downloads)."
2. Your Favorites will appear first.  Click on the icon to the right of the star icon.  It looks like the Weather app's icon for "Windy."  The tooltip for this icon is "Reading List."

You will now see the items you have saved to your "Reading List."

[Reading List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhdHd.png)

References:  https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/chrome-reading-list/

Answer (score 0):

I found it. There is a Reading List folder somewhere three levels down in the bookmarks folder structure. Strange enough, in the folder-selection list that is shown when creating a bookmark, it's listed as a top-level folder. This is confusing. But at least, now I have my bookmarks back.